# Ускорение рисунка turtle

Tags: python, turtle

Я делаю фрактал Леви на Python с помощью turtle. У меня получается но рисуется очень медленно. Мне надо завтра сдать эту работу но не хочется, чтобы учитель долго стоял и смотрел как она рисуется.

Вот код:

```py
import turtle

def draw(n):
    if n == 0:
        turtle.forward(10)
    
    else:
        turtle.left(45)
        draw(n - 1)
        turtle.right(45)
        turtle.right(45)
        draw(n - 1)
        turtle.left(45)

draw(20)
```

Comment: Код необходимо прикреплять в качестве текста

Comment: А где часть, где фрактал? Там нужно тормоза искать... тут тормозов нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы ускорить черепашку, используйте команду `turtle.speed (n)`, **n**– скорость черепашки. **n** должно быть целым числом больше или равным нулю.
Ноль – самая большая скорость, доступная для использования.
То есть, вот ваша программа:

```
import turtle
def draw(n):
    if n == 0:
        turtle.forward(10)
    
    else:
        turtle.left(45)
        draw(n - 1)
        turtle.right(45)
        turtle.right(45)
        draw(n - 1)
        turtle.left(45)
turtle.speed(0)
draw(20)
```

***Быстрее нельзя, это и так самая быстрая черепашка***

начало ответа взято [отсюда](http://itrobo.ru/programmirovanie/python/grafika-turtle-cherepashka-v-piton.html#:%7E:text=%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D1%83%2C%20%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5,%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Answer (score 2):

В таких случаях я вызываю в начале кода функцию tracer() из модуля turtle, а когда нужно отрисовать, вызываю функцию update() из того же модуля.
В примере отрисовка производится всего 100 раз на более чем 200тыс движений

```
turtle.tracer(0)
t = turtle.Turtle()
for i in range(1000):
    t.goto(0, 0)
    t.lt(1.001)
    for j in range(100):
        t.fd(i)
        t.color('white') if i % 2 else t.color('black')
        t.lt(173)
    if not i % 10:
        turtle.update()
```